# AFNetworkReachabilityManager EXC_BAD_ACCESS in swift when referencing self

Tags: swift, afnetworking

When calling setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock within a view controller, the following code throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. I'm pretty sure what is happening is that the self object is no longer referenced when the block is executed. What is the right way to provide a reference to self within the code block?

In the sample code below, commenting out the self.description code allows this to work. (Note: I'm on Xcode 6 beta 4)

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock{(status: AFNetworkReachabilityStatus?)          in

        switch status!.hashValue{
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.NotReachable.hashValue:                
            println("Not reachable")                
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.ReachableViaWiFi.hashValue , AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.ReachableViaWWAN.hashValue :
            println("Reachable")
            println(self.description)  // Seems to cause error
        default:
            println("Unknown status")
        }
}
```

Comment: Here is a workaround using a separate [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) project. 
       

`let r = Reachability(hostname: "www.google.com")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver( self, selector: "foo:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
        r.startNotifier()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem trying to use the AFNetworking reachability code from within a RestKit-based project. Apparently, as the OP notes, self is no longer available for reference when the block is executed. I had already set up my class that contains the reachability code as a singleton so instead of referencing self I referenced the singleton shared instance and it works.

Here is the singleton setup code:

```
class var sharedInstance: MyClass {
    struct Static {
        static let instance = MyClass()
    }
    return Static.instance
}
```

I can now reference the shared instance as:

```
MyClass.sharedInstance
```

So using that pattern you could update your block to be the following and it should work:

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock{(status: AFNetworkReachabilityStatus?)          in

    switch status!.hashValue{
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.NotReachable.hashValue:                
        println("Not reachable")                
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.ReachableViaWiFi.hashValue , AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.ReachableViaWWAN.hashValue :
        println("Reachable")
        println(MyClass.sharedInstance.description)  // Seems to cause error
    default:
        println("Unknown status")
    }
}
```